# How can I print out all but the last n characters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, tr

I'm working with standard input (`cat`ing two files together) and want all but the last 10 characters of the result to be passed through the next command.

All I can find through searching is using `sed`, `awk` or `tr` to remove the last n characters from each line, or `head`, `tail` or `rev` to remove n lines.

What could I use to do this from standard output piped into a command (hopefully simply and with a single command)?

Example:

```
Input:
SELECT 'A', 1, GETDATE() UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, GETDATE() UNION ALL
...
SELECT 'Z', 2, GETDATE() UNION ALL

Output:
SELECT 'A', 1, GETDATE() UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, GETDATE() UNION ALL
...
SELECT 'Z', 2, GETDATE()
```

For what it's worth, I'm using CygWin on Windows, so it needs to be with rather standard and old unix tools :(

Comment: Look at the last line, with 'Z'. The last 10 characters have been removed (the final `UNION ALL`), which makes it valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `head`:

```
command | head -c-10
```

would remove the last 10 bytes from `command` output.

Quoting from `man head`:

```
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each  file;  with  the  leading  `-',
          print all but the last K bytes of each file
```

---

Since you specifically mention that the 10 characters to be removed would occur on one line, you could use `sed` too.  Pipe the command output to:

```
sed '$s/\(.\{10\}\)$//'
```

or if your `sed` supports extended regex:

```
sed -r '$s/.{10}$//'
```

---

The syntax would be similar using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/.{10}$// if eof'
```

Comment: Does not appear to be supported in CygWin, `head --version = 2.0 (1999)`. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Ehryk The `sed` alternative might work for you.

Comment: The `sed` one works. How do you match on {end of stream} and not {end of line}?

Comment: @Ehryk The `$` (before the `s`) is an _address_ that specifies the last line.

Comment: How does this work with multibyte characters, like UTF-8?

Comment: @evilsoup Please post a [new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you have a question.  This question doesn't make any mention of multibyte characters.

Comment: Unfortunately the -c-n option form seems to be specific to GNU head (from GNU coreutils). The head program I have on MacOS/Darwin -- which comes from BSD -- doesn't support it. I have not checked the POSIX docs but I expect it is nonstandard.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `perl`:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_=substr($_,0,-10) if eof' file
SELECT 'A', 1, GETDATE() UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2, GETDATE() UNION ALL
...
SELECT 'Z', 2, GETDATE()
```

Comment: Cool, that works, too! (Now I just have to figure out how to pipe it into sqlcmd and get it to execute it).